# How to do empty field validation in datatables 1.9.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

When clicking "AddNew" Button,datatable is creating a new record with empty/null value.How to avoid this?

Note: 
I'm using datatables in bootstrap portlet box layout.how to show alert error message when adding a null value in datatables??

Comment: Use jquery validation. This is [Demo](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/basic-jquery-validation-form/)

Comment: need more description for your issue

Comment: Here is the sample [datatable example](http://datatables.net/blog/Inline_editing).add a new row/clear the existing row valu,click save it will create a empty record without any validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this sample [link](http://datatables.net/blog/Inline_editing) in the Edit click event i have added simple empty field validation for the first column.

```
$('#exampleTable a.edit').live('click', function (e) {    
e.preventDefault();      
var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];   
if (nEditing !== null && nEditing != nRow) {
    /*if Currently editing - but not this row - restore the old before continuing to edit mode */
    restoreRow(oTable, nEditing);
    editRow(oTable, nRow);
    nEditing = nRow;
} else if (nEditing == nRow && this.innerHTML == "Save") {
    /* else Editing this row and want to save it */
   var newEntry = $((oTable.fnGetData(nRow)).edit).attr("data-mode") == "new";
   var jqValInputs = $('input', nEditing);
   if(jqValInputs[0].value.length == 0)
   {
       alert("Name cannot be empty");
       return false;
   }
    saveRow(oTable, nEditing);
    nEditing = null;
    oTable.fnUpdate(data.id, nRow, 0, false);
 } else {
    editRow(oTable, nRow);
    nEditing = nRow;
}
});
```

Comment: The alert, return false appears as the best option instead of adding more complex jquery validation.  Thanks for answering your question, it helped me with my datatables.

Comment: make sure nNew = true; before return false after alert.  This will prevent when cancel is click a blank row will not be created.